# Jekyll : array_to_sentence_string undefined method

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

A sample post with tags defined in the front matter

```
---
layout : blog
tags: health, covid
---

# COVID-19 vaccines: Get the facts

Looking to get the facts about the new COVID-19 vaccines? Here's what you need to know about the different vaccines and the benefits of getting vaccinated.
```

I want the tags to be joined and display in the post.

There is a filter called `array_to_sentence_string` which basically concatenates all the tags as documented in the documentation  (Yes, without the need to loop each tag manually)

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/

I used `{{ page.tags | array_to_sentence_string  }}` in the code to display the tags.

However, I keep getting the following error message during the build process.

```
lib/jekyll/filters.rb:153:in `array_to_sentence_string': undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I found the solution. I added `map: 'to_liquid'` to the object and it started working.

```
{{ page.tags | map: 'to_liquid' | array_to_sentence_string  }}
```

Here is the full code of the page

```
---
layout: main
---
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p class="info">    
    {{ page.date | date_to_string }} 
    Tags :  {{ page.tags | map: 'to_liquid' | array_to_sentence_string  }}
</p>

{{ content }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the format of your tags - currently a string. I tend to avoid the space separated categories and tags format for reasons like this. Although you have found a workaround, another solution could be to change it into an array:

```
tags:
  - health
  - covid
```